# Are there specific location/locations where a solar gravitational lens telescopes would be placed?

Tags: space-telescope

I was thinking about solar-gravitational lens telescopes and it occurred to me that a particular telescope would likely have to be selected in opposition to a particular small spot of sky.   That is, the telescope itself can't be turned, it has to face the sun, and from 550 AU distance, it's not very convenient to move it around a whole lot.   Maybe a few AU but that uses fuel, both to accelerate towards the new spot and then to decelerate.   It would be much easier to mostly let it drift in orbit, with smaller adjustments.

My question is, have there been discussions on what direction the first lensing telescopes should look towards?   I gather the big advantage is much better resolution and they'd be very cold so they could look in IR as well as visible light.

Exoplanets?   Very early galaxy formation?  Others?   Would they just look into empty space and see what's there (like they did with Hubble and the dark spot in the sky) - probably a bit of each I would think, but my main question is, has there been any discussion on what points in the sky should be studied?  Even if the technology is 100 years away from operating, that doesn't mean it's not been discussed by astronomers.  Are there particular favorite locations to eventually set up gravitational lens telescopes.   Everything I've read says what they can do, but not where they would put them.

Comment: Although this is on-topic for Space Exploration, you might get better answers asking it on Astronomy.

Comment: @DrSheldon  I meant to post it in astronomy for the "discussions on where to put them"part.   I must have had a senior moment.   Oh well.